Table header shifting the right after clicking button
I have a table that works beautifullly but for some reason when I click on my testing button the table headers shift to the right. I tried using `style="position:fixed" and I tried taking out the thead in my table neither one worked. I can't find any other resources with my exact problem. Any help is appreciated.
LangInfo view:
@model OfficerLangVM

<body>
<div class="full-width">
    <h4>Language Information</h4>
    <table style="background-color:lightgray; width:75%" class="table table-boardered table-striped" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>Fluency</th>
                <th>Read</th>
                <th>Write</th>
                <th>Speak</th>
                <th>Understand</th>
                <th>Date Modified</th>
                <th><!--Edit--></th>
                <th><!--Delete--></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="OfficerKey" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="AgGuid" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="LanguageKey"/>
            @{
                if (Model.Languages != null)
                {
                    int rownum = 0;
                    foreach (Language lang in Model.Languages)
                    {
                            <tr id="@rownum">
                                <td>@lang.LanguageName</td>
                                <td>@lang.Fluency</td>
                                @if (lang.CanRead == true)
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                }
                                @if (lang.CanWrite == true)
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                }
                                @if (lang.CanSpeak == true)
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                }
                                @if (lang.CanUnderstand == true)
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                }
                                    <td>@lang.DateUpdated</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <!--Testing to keep user on same view page, doesn't pull an info-->
                                        <input type="button" value="testing" onclick="show(@lang.LanguageKey); hide(@rownum)"/> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <!--This works just takes user to new view page-->
                                        <a asp-action="LanguageUpdate" asp-route-id="@lang.LanguageKey">Edit</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a asp-action="DeleteLang" asp-route-id="@lang.LanguageKey">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:none" id="@lang.LanguageKey">
                                @await Html.PartialAsync("LanguageUpdate", lang)
                            </tr>
                        rownum++;
                    }
                }
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(key) {
        document.getElementById(key).style.display = "block";
    }

    function hide(rownum) {
        document.getElementById(rownum).style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

<style>

    .body-container {
        /*remove the container default padding attribute*/
        /*padding-left: 0px !important;
                padding-right: 0px !important;*/
        /*increase width as per your need*/
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>

LanguageUpdate view that is called from testing button:
@model Language

<form asp-action="UpdateLang" method="post">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="OfficerKey" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="AgGuid" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="LanguageKey" />
@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        <td>
            <select asp-for="LanguageName">
                <option Value=""> 1) Select a Language . . .</option>
                <option value="American Sign English (ASE)">American Sign English (ASE)</option>
                <option value="American Sign Language (ASL)">American Sign Language (ASL)</option>
                <option value="Arabic: Algerian">Arabic: Algerian</option>
                <option value="Arabic: Egyptian">Arabic: Egyptian</option>
                <option value="Awadhi">Awadhi</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijani">Azerbaijani</option>
                <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
                <option value="Bhojpuri">Bhojpuri</option>
                <option value="Chinese: Cantonese">Chinese: Cantonese</option>
                <option value="Chinese: Fukein">Chinese: Fukein</option>
                <option value="Chinese: Jinyu">Chinese: Jinyu</option>
                <option value="Chinese: Mandarin">Chinese: Mandarin</option>
                <option value="Chinese: Min Nan">Chinese: Min Nan</option>
                <option value="Chinese: Wu">Chinese: Wu</option>
                <option value="Creole">Creole</option>
                <option value="Creole-Jamaican">Creole-Jamaican</option>
                <option value="Czech">Czech</option>
                <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
                <option value="Esperanza">Esperanza</option>
                <option value="Estonian">Estonian</option>
                <option value="Farsi">Farsi</option>
                <option value="French">French</option>
                <option value="Gaelic">Gaelic</option>
                <option value="German">German</option>
                <option value="Greek">Greek</option>
                <option value="Hausa">Hausa</option>
                <option value="Hebrew">Hebrew</option>
                <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
                <option value="Hmong">Hmong</option>
                <option value="Hungarian">Hungarian</option>
                <option value="Icelandic">Icelandic</option>
                <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
                <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
                <option value="Kannada">Kannada</option>
                <option value="Korean">Korean</option>
                <option value="Lao">Lao</option>
                <option value="Latin">Latin</option>
                <option value="Maithili">Maithili</option>
                <option value="Marathi">Marathi</option>
                <option value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
                <option value="Native American: Blackfoot">Native American: Blackfoot</option>
                <option value="Native American: Cheyenne">Native American: Cheyenne</option>
                <option value="Native American: Chippewa">Native American: Chippewa</option>
                <option value="Native American: Cree">Native American: Cree</option>
                <option value="Native American: Dakota">Native American: Dakota</option>
                <option value="Native American: Lakota">Native American: Lakota</option>
                <option value="Native American: Lenape">Native American: Lenape</option>
                <option value="Native American: Navajo">Native American: Navajo</option>
                <option value="Native American: Ojibwi">Native American: Ojibwii</option>
                <option value="Native American: Oneida">Native American: Oneida</option>
                <option value="Native American: Onodaga">Native American: Onodaga</option>
                <option value="Native American: Paivte">Native American: Paivte</option>
                <option value="Native American: Shoshoni">Native American: Shoshoni</option>
                <option value="Native American: Sioux">Native American: Sioux</option>
                <option value="Niger-Congo: Akan">Niger-Congo: Akan</option>
                <option value="Niger-Congo: Twi">Niger-Congo: Twi</option>
                <option value="Norwegian">Norwegian</option>
                <option value="Oriya">Oriya</option>
                <option value="Panjabi">Panjabi</option>
                <option value="Patois">Patois</option>
                <option value="Polish">Polish</option>
                <option value="Portuguese">Portuguese</option>
                <option value="Romanian">Romanian</option>
                <option value="Russian">Russian</option>
                <option value="Serbian">Serbian</option>
                <option value="Serbo-croatian">Serbo-croatian</option>
                <option value="Sign Language">Sign Language</option>
                <option value="Sindhi">Sindhi</option>
                <option value="Slovaic(Slovak)">Slovaic(Slovak</option>
                <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                <option value="Sunda">Sunda</option>
                <option value="Swedish">Swedish</option>
                <option value="Tagalog">Tagalog</option>
                <option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
                <option value="Telugu">Telugu</option>
                <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
                <option value="Turkish">Turkish</option>
                <option value="Ukrainian">Ukrainian</option>
                <option value="Urdu">Urdu</option>
                <option value="Vietnamese">Vietnamese</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select asp-for="Fluency">
                <option value="1) Limited Proficiency">1. Limited Proficiency</option>
                <option value="2) Novice">2. Novice</option>
                <option value="3) Intermediate">3. Intermediate</option>
                <option value="4) Advanced">4. Advanced</option>
                <option value="5) Native Speaker">5. Native Speaker</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        @if (Model.CanRead == true)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanRead))
            </td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanRead))
            </td>
       }
       @if (Model.CanWrite == true)
       {
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanWrite))
            </td>
       }
       else
       {
           <td>
               @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanWrite))
           </td>
       }
       @if (Model.CanSpeak == true)
       {
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanSpeak))
            </td>
       }
       else
       {
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanSpeak))</td>
       }
       @if (Model.CanUnderstand == true)
       {
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanUnderstand))
            </td>
       }
       else
       {
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor((modelItem => Model.CanUnderstand))</td>
       }
       <td>@Model.DateUpdated</td>
       <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:lightgray; color:black" />
       </td>
       <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:lightgray; color:black" asp-action="DeleteLang" asp-route-id="@Model.LanguageKey" />
       </td>
       <td>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Editing" asp-route-id="@Model.OfficerKey" value="Cancel" style="background-color:lightgray; color:black" />
       </td>
    }
}    

Controller:
public IActionResult LanguageUpdate (int id)
{
  Language lang = getLanguage(id);

  return View(lang);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateLang(Language UpdateLang)
{
  MailkitErrors errors = new(ServiceProvider!, Configuration!);

  UserEmail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserEmail")!;

  string ConnectionString = connectionStrings.Get("ForeignLanguageConnectString");

  var objLangUpdateConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
  var objLangUdDataSet = new DataSet();
  string strLangUpdate = "UpdateLanguage";
  try
  {
    var objCommandlang = new SqlCommand(strLangUpdate, objLangUpdateConnect);
    objCommandlang.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Add parameters for input
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowCount", 1);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficerKey", UpdateLang.OfficerKey);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LanguageKey", UpdateLang.LanguageKey);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LanguageName", UpdateLang.LanguageName);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fluency", UpdateLang.Fluency);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanRead", UpdateLang.CanRead);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanWrite", UpdateLang.CanWrite);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanSpeak", UpdateLang.CanSpeak);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanUnderstand", UpdateLang.CanUnderstand);
    objCommandlang.Parameters.Add("@UserUpdated", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = "";

    var ObjDataAdapterLang = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommandlang);
    ObjDataAdapterLang.Fill(objLangUdDataSet, "Language"); //FLIPV2 dbo.Language Table
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "There has been an error. MAGLOCLEN HelpDesk has been notified.";
    errors.ErrorEmails(UserEmail, "Error occured while updating language for selected officer:\n");
}

UpdateLang.Officer = getOfficer(UpdateLang.OfficerKey);
UpdateLang.syncOfficer();
return RedirectToAction("Editing", new { id = UpdateLang.OfficerKey });

}

I changed the script in the LangInfo view from
function show(key) {
    document.getElementById(key).style.display = "block";
}

to
function show(key) {
    document.getElementById(key).style.display = "contents";
}

